# Webdriver: How to select anchor link under DIV?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In below code when I use //a[text()='My Process1' in Firebug it evaluates xpath and returns correctly, however when I try to use the same for finding an element using WebDriver I get NoSuchElement exception....any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
    <div class="abbd" style="">
    <ul class="New-type">
    <li class="abcmenuitem" id="yui-gen10" groupindex="0" index="3"><a href="#" class="abcmenuitemlabel">My Process1</a></li>
    <li class="abcmenuitem" id="yui-gen11" groupindex="0" index="4"><a href="#" class="abcmenuitemlabel">My Process2</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
webDriver.findElment(By.linkText("My Process1"));
```

Comment: Thanks Phil for quick response, have tried it...it is not working :( I get Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with link text == General Inquiry (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 374 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: I'm using webdriver, this one works well. Are you sure your webpage contains the link. You can print out the web page with webDriver.getPageSource().

Comment: Phil - I cannot find anything with text ..."My Process1" on source

Comment: Then that's not a problem with webDriver, you should go back and check your application functionality. Are you using FirefoxDriver with WebDriver? With FirefoxDirver, you can watch what's going on on the pop-up firefox browser

Comment: You can use absolute xpath

Comment: You may want to add the code you tried in your question.  Did your code look something like this?  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@text()=\"My Process1\"]"));

Comment: Also, assuming you're using a local driver instead of RemoteWebDriver, you can debug and pause on the element find.  Open firebug there and see if the element actually does exist at that time.  I once spent 2 hours trying to figure out why WebDriver didn't find an element only to find out the element didn't exist yet.